# Reflect Map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection, hashmap

In `Java`, having shared storage:

```
final Map<String, Car> cars = (numberOfThreads == 1)
        ? new HashMap<String, Car>()
        : new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Car>();
```

then in the `run()` method of a thread worker class I want to store concurrently data into the `cars` map. For that I need to downcast to an appropriate hashmap instance. I could use `if (numberOfThreads == 1)` but I guess it is possible to reflect the `cars` object - how can I use Java Reflection API here?

I get this error: `The method putIfAbsent(String, Car) is undefined for the type Map<String, Car>` so I have to downcast.

Comment: First, why would you even want to downcast? The `Map` API should satisfy your needs in either case. Second, if you really do need access to `ConcurrentMap` API methods not available on `Map`, don't bother using a non-concurrent `HashMap` in the simple case, just use a `ConcurrentHashMap` all the time. The idea of using reflection here is really bad.

Comment: I agree with @gknicker. If you really want to distinguish between single- and multithreaded, you should probably use [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to implement these two methods instead of having ifs all around in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to your question:

```
if (cars instanceof ConcurrentMap) {
    ((ConcurrentMap)cars).putIfAbsent(key, value);
}
```

However, in Java 8 the [`Map` interface now has `putIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-), so this casting would not be necessary if you can upgrade your JDK.

If you can't use Java 8 I would recommend using a `ConcurrentMap` all the time, because this sort of `instanceof` code is not worth the tradeoff.

In any case, the Java reflection API is inappropriate for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to downcast, just use Map put method, nothing else needs to be done.

Since the question changed, than yes, there is no putIfAbsent method. Without seeing the code, one could only guess.

Finally are you sure you need putIfAbsent, would there be a problem if you put the same car twice?

Comment: I get this error: `The method putIfAbsent(String, Car) is undefined for the type Map<String, Car>` so I have to downcast.

Comment: `putIfAbsent` doesn't look like `put` to me.

Comment: upgrade to Java8 where `Map` interface now has `putIfAbsent()`

Comment: I see, if you include your code that you were using it could be more helpful. As mentioned in the comment you can always use concurrent map, and finally, do you really need putIfAbsent